# Javascript, if value is a certain text and checked, show image

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, input, checked

I'm trying to automate my ribbons for my GTA ONLINE crew website, and rather than having to hand-code; I create checkboxes with "ultimate-member" and then use javascript to check if a field is checked and display the image.

Here's what I have

```js
<script>
    if (document.getElementsByName("platform").value === "Medal Of Honor" && document.getElementsByName("platform").checked ) { {
        document.getElementByID().innerHTML ='<img src="http://www.8492nd.org/img/awards/Medal-Of-Honor.png" alt="" />';
    }
 </script>
```

```html
<h1>code beta</h1>
   <input type="checkbox" name="platform[]" value="Medal Of Honor" checked />Medal of Honor


<div id="awards-ribbons">
</div>
```

I tried to put the code inside the div, and simply have it write the image out based on which boxes are checked. problem I ran into is that the input doesn't have an ID or Class attribute; and I cannot change it. If I could locate the PHP of "ultimate-member" I would add an id based on the value of checkbox. Then I could use the getElementById(id).checked and I'll be good to go.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns multiple elements, so you need an index. `document.getElementByID` doesn’t exist: it’s `Id`, not `ID`. Also it requires an argument.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the field is set initially...since you are not running this inside any event handlers, it will not update dynamically once the user checks it.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but 3 mistakes need to be corrected.

1. `getElementsByName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, so you need to access specfic items by *index*
2. `getElementByID` is incorrect, it needs to be `getElementById` (lower-case *d* at the end)
3. You need to pass in the id when using `getElementById`

---

```
if (document.getElementsByName("platform")[0].value === "Medal Of Honor" && document.getElementsByName("platform")[0].checked ) { {
        document.getElementById("awards-ribbons").innerHTML ='<img src="" alt="" />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your if statement, the `document.getElementById()` expression doesn't have an argument passed to it.  You should pass to it the id of the element that you want to change.

```
document.getElementByID('idOfElement').innerHTML ='<img src="http://www.8492nd.org/img/awards/Medal-Of-Honor.png" alt="" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
p = document.getElementsByName("platform")[0];
    if (p.value === "Medal Of Honor" && p.checked ) { 
        document.getElementById('awards-ribbons').innerHTML ='<img src="http://www.8492nd.org/img/awards/Medal-Of-Honor.png" alt="" />';
    }
```

```html
<h1>code beta</h1>
   <input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Medal Of Honor" checked />Medal of Honor


<div id="awards-ribbons">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I tried all of these but it didn't seem to work.

Here's the thing with "ultimate-member" they don't use IDs, it's strictly class. so I did try getting the element by class name and nothing.

Then I noticed the input checkboxes, do not have an ID or class assigned to them?

Is it possible to say:

"if checkbox checked and value = "medal of honor" --> show image"?

that seems to be the only way for it to work.